# R: I think I have enough memory but still...Error: cannot allocate vector of size 949.2 Mb

Tags: r, memory

In R studio

```
memory.size(max=F) #I thought this means much much memory I've used

[1] 109.92

memory.size(max=T) #how much I have in total

[1] 2251.31

binnedtemp <- binning_median(IVMtemp,TimeStep,starttime)

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 949.2 Mb
```

I don't understand... I also tried memory.limit(24000), and the error message still came up.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look [here](https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/Memory-limits.html). You cannot allocate the whole memory to one vector, there are other limits to be considered.